# How to interpret three/four-way interactions(continous) in logistic regression model through plotting in R

Tags: logistic, interaction, ggplot2

There are four variables have significant interaction effects in my logistic regression model, but I still did not get good way to interpret it through R software.

There are some discussion on 3-way interactions, it seems that plot would be a way. But their discussions are for linear regression rather than logistic regression

For the two-way interaction, I used the ggplot to plot the probability with three groups moderation variable setting (min, mean, max), please see the attached plot for two-way interaction

[image]

Now I really would like to ask how to plot three/four-way interactions in logistic regression model in order to interpret this interactions well.